# Calling authenticated vs public Google Cloud function from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I followed [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#exchanging_a_self-signed_jwt_for_a_google-signed_id_token) to get the bearer token to successfully call an authenticated HTTP Google Cloud function from my Android Flutter app. The function processes a Braintree payment nonce. I had to include the "`service_account`" JSON in my project, which has `private_key` and `private_key_id` fields. This JSON is stored as an asset in my app.

I am concerned about storing this private information in my app. Would it be better to have my function public and not store this information in the app?

Comment: Your question lacks detail and so it's difficult to propose alternatives but, yes, you should be reluctant to bundle a Service Account key in your app. Not only could the key be compromised but you'll be challenged to e.g. rotate it. You probably want to use OAuth to authenticate your users and then consider implementing your own authorization mechanism in your Cloud Functions to limit what gets access to your app. See [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and [Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform).

Comment: My app does not require any logins. The cloud function is a payment handler for Braintree. There doesn't seem to be a good pre-built way to authenticate calls to an HTTP Cloud function from a mobile app.